# ¿Como sustituir valores de algunas filas de un dataframe en R?

Tags: r, dataframe

el caso es el siguiente:

Tengo un dataframe de varias miles de filas con datos de temperaturas por horas, días, meses y años de una ciudad. Algunas filas (la minoría), la captura de datos registró como hora un formato XX:59:59, haciendo referencia a horas:minutos:segundos, otras filas (la mayoría) la captura de datos se realizó en XX:00:00, entonces quisiera que todas las que tiene el formato de captura XX:59:59, sumarles un segundo para llevarles a la hora siguiente y queden en XX:00:00.

Gracias por sus orientaciones y comentarios

Comment: Hola, si adjuntas el codigo que tienes hasta el momento / lo que has intentado los usuarios te podran ayudar mejor

Comment: ¿Algo así?: grouped_df [50,403 × 5] (S3: grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Año      : chr [1:50403] "2004" "2004" "2004" "2004" ...
 $ Mes      : chr [1:50403] "01" "01" "01" "01" ...
 $ Dia      : chr [1:50403] "01" "01" "01" "01" ...
 $ Hora     : chr [1:50403] "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "01:00:00" ...
 $ Promedios: num [1:50403] 9.93 12.73 10.41 9.14 12.58 ...

Comment: El problema es que pasa con una hora que sea `23:59:59` sumarle un segundo debería cambiar la fecha que por lo que veo tienes descompuesta en varias columnas

Comment: Pero podría convertir esas cuatro columnas en una sola de fecha/hora y luego hacer el cambio. Lo que no logro resolver es cómo convertir todas las filas que terminan en 59:59 en 00:00. Alguna sugerencia @PatricioMoracho ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece un problema simple, pero no lo es tanto, lidiar con fechas tiene su trabajo. Como te decía, el problema lo tienes con horas como `23:59:59` dónde sumar un segundo implica el cambio del día y en tu caso tienes cada parte de la fecha separada, algo como esto:

```
df <- data.frame(Año="2004", Mes="01", Dia="01", Hora="23:59:59")
df

   Año Mes Dia     Hora
1 2004  01  01 23:59:59
```

Por lo que el primer paso es "juntar" todo en una nueva columna  del tipo "fecha":

```
df$Fecha <- with(df, as.POSIXct(paste0(Año, Mes, Dia, Hora), 
                       format = "%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S" ))
```

Y luego, finalmente sumar un segundo a la fecha en los casos esperados:

```
df$Fecha <- with(df, ifelse(substr(Hora, 4, 9) == "59:59", 
                            Fecha + 1, 
                            Fecha))
```

Hay un problema adicional, el `ifelse` tiene la costumbre de no mantener la clase del objeto, por lo que deberemos volver a establecerla:

```
class(df$Fecha) <- "POSIXct"
df
   Año Mes Dia     Hora      Fecha
1 2004  01  01 23:59:59 2004-01-02
```

Y por último, volvemos a "desarmar" la fecha:

```
df$new_Año <- format(df$Fecha,"%Y")
df$new_Mes <- format(df$Fecha,"%m")
df$new_Dia <- format(df$Fecha,"%d")
df$new_Hora <- format(df$Fecha,"%H:%M:%S")
df

   Año Mes Dia     Hora      Fecha new_Año new_Mes new_Dia new_Hora
1 2004  01  01 23:59:59 2004-01-02    2004      01      02 00:00:00
```